# Заменить латинские буквы аналогичными кирилическими по кодам символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки, unicode

Добрый день.

Задача следующая, необходимо строку "vjcrdf" заменить на строку "москва".

Логика понятна, что нужно взять каждый символ и добавить к нему определенную константу, чтобы он стал аналогичным в кирилице.

Однако как это сделать?
Код типа:

```
$search_string = mb_convert_encoding ($search_string, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($search_string));
    $search_string = preg_split('//u',$search_string,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 
    foreach($search_string as $char)
    {
        $intChar = ord($char);
        $intChar += 90;
        $correct_string[] = chr($intChar);
    }
    $correct_string = implode("", $correct_string);
    var_dump($correct_string);
```

Не работает. Кто поможет?

Answer (score 0):

Если решать задачу в лоб, то надо просто составить таблицу кириллических и латинских символов, и производить замену по ней. Это будет самый надежный вариант в плане стабильности работы.

Первая строка вообще не понятна, зачем менять кодировку, когда требуется просто произвести замену одного символа на другой? К тому же, mb_detect_encoding - не всегда верно определяет кодировку. Точнее он не определяет, а "угадывает" ее по определенным паттернам.

ord - возвращает ASCII-код символа. Как вы ищите этот код, когда вы уже сконвертировали строку в UTF-8? chr - также работает с ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Делал что то похожее ранее , принцип только был немного другой ,
у меня было при вводе в текстбокс сразу преобразование. 
Вот переменные для сравнения

```
Dim rus$ = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮёЁ"
Dim eng$ = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,.QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL;'ZXCVBNM,.`~"
```

если хочешь как выше написал с константами  - тогда так

A_Z код клавы 65-90,  a-z код клавы 97-122

А-Я код клавы 192-233, а-я код клавы 224-155

для 65 кода клавы - кириллица 212 код = константа 147 и так далее

для каждого символа константу выводить ручками из списка ...

далее анг букву преобразовали в код клавы , к нему прибавили константу , и перевели код клавы в символьный

код клавы = Asc(символа)

Символ рус = Chr(код клавы + константа )

или одной записью  Символ рус = Chr(Asc(англ символа) + константа )